# Load File Flex 2

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, flex2

How to load a file from a user selection?

In later flex versions is available the method FileReference.load(). But in flex 2 there isn't.

I want to do something like this:

```
var fileRef:FileReference= new FileReference();
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);

function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    fileRef.browse([new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png")]);
    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
}

function onFileSelected(e:Event):void {
    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
    fileRef.load();
}

function onFileLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.loadBytes(e.target.data);
}
```

Comment: Flex2 is using actionscript 3, not 2 (I think Flex 1.5 was on as2). Does this need to be compiled with the Flex2SDK ? Why not switch to FlexSDK 3 or newer (with Flash Player 10 support and FileReference's load()) ? Also, another option is to switch to AIR and use the flash.desktop.File API.

Comment: This code is for an addon for an application that only supports Flex2. I don't know about switching to AIR, I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I can't use AIR for developing the addon.